# Slicing or masking?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm not sure if there's a general answer to my question, but I wonder whether array masking or slicing is "better" to manipulate only parts of an array. With "better" I mean with respect to performance (speed of performing manipulations, memory overhead, i.e. intermediate arrays, etc). Is there any rule of thumb as to which one to use?

Comment: 'masked' maybe interpreted as using `np.ma` or a more basic `my_array[my_boolean_mask]` which creates a copy. Which do you mean?

Comment: Slicing would prob be better because it frees memory. While masking keeps it in the cache.

Comment: I meant `np.ma`. I understood `my_array[my_boolean_mask]` as a way of slicing.

Comment: Edit your question.  Add some examples, to clear up confusion.

Answer (score 1):

These are some results using `timeit`

```
import numpy as np

x= np.arange(10000)

% timeit x[[np.arange(0,10000,2)]]
#output: 10000 loops, best of 3: 41.4 µs per loop
```

Assigning the indexed values to another array

```
% timeit z = x[[np.arange(0,10000,2)]]
#output: 10000 loops, best of 3: 41.9 µs per loop
```

or, assigning values to the indexed array

```
% timeit x[[np.arange(0,10000,2)]] = 1
#output: 1000 loops, best of 3: 151 µs per loop
```

Now let's try the same using masking:

```
x = np.ma.array(np.arange(10000))

% timeit x.mask = [1 if i%2==0 else 0 for i in np.arange(10000)]
#output: 100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop
```

If you already have values to mask stored

```
maskValues = [1 if i%2==0 else 0 for i in np.arange(10000)]

% timeit x.mask = maskValues
# output: 1000 loops, best of 3: 712 µs per loop
```

So indexing in numpy proved to be simpler and faster for this example

Answer (score 1):

It should also be noted that you can create a reusable `slice` object rather than a mask or array of indexes (assuming a contiguous or regularly-spaced slice) that is very small and very fast.

```py
n = 10000
test_array = np.arange(n)

# Mask
mask = np.ones(n, dtype=bool)
mask &= test_array >= 50
mask &= test_array < 9500

# Slice object
slc = slice(50, 9500)
```

Timing the mask:

```py
%timeit test_array[mask]
#output: 10.8 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Timing the slice object:

```py
%timeit test_array[slc]
#output: 200 ns ± 1.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Of course this is best for 1-D use.